# Google Colaboratory shows error when saving a file to Github " Could not fetch branches. "

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

Created a (assuming public) repo on Github and when saving a file from [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/), it shows a warning or error "Could not fetch branches."

The repo is absolutely empty. Do I need to add anything to it?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this in the future, the trick is to initialize the (public) repository with a readme and then it works as intended.